# Windows Driver Loader?

Tags: windows, debugging, logging, driver

Debug Messages from the Windows Kernel Drivers?

I am using DbgPrint and DebugView currently, but it this the official way to observe the drivers behaviour? Does anybody know if and where kernel log files are hidden in the Windows System (like /var/log and dmesg only windows-ish?)

I for my part are currently using Vista, but there probably is some standard or hidden way of logging which is much older but still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API for the event log in kernel mode.

See [IoAllocateErrorLogEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms801569.aspx) and [IoWriteErrorLogEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa490465.aspx).

I don't know if they are slow or fast.

You should use DbgPrint for trace calls and use WinDbg from the [Windows kernel debugging tools](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) for debugging your drivers. WinDbg is a really good debugger, which will help you greatly.

PS: this is not hidden in any way. See the WDK documentation for details.

Comment: knowing the right terms to search for is halfways there. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of /var/log is the Event Log but you can't use it for drivers because that would be too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Use WPP Software Tracing. See ["Tracing and Diagnosability for WDF Drivers"](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/tools/EventTrace.mspx).

WPP is based on Event Tracing for Windows (ETW), a kernel-level facility that logs trace messages for both kernel-mode and user-mode processes.

WPP has a few advantages over debug print statements :

- can be enabled, disabled & filtered runtime, in release builds as well

  time stamps, function names, line numbers etc can be automatically included in each entry

  high performance

  traces can be automatically included in the crash mini dumps

For error messages meant for the end user, use the Event Log.